# PHP form validation and error reporting

Tags: php, validation, report

I am new to php and I wanted to implement some php form validation to the website I have been working on. Previously I used javascript to validate the form contents but I have heard php is a better method to do so.

I have tried to implement some php to my website so that fields are validated, however I think I must be doing something wrong as currently nothing functions as it should.

Here is the php code I am currently working with:

```
<?php
 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
     if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $nameErr = "Missing";
    }
     else {
        $name = $_POST["name"];
    }

    if (empty($_POST["tele"])) {
        $teleErr = "Missing";
    }
    else {
        $tele = $_POST["tele"];
    }

    if (empty($_POST["email"]))  {
        $emailErr = "Missing";
    }
    else {
        $email = $_POST["email"];
    }

    if (empty($_POST["party"])) {
        $partyErr = "You must select 1";
    }
    else {
        $party = $_POST["party"];
    }

    if (!isset($_POST["hand"])) {
        $handErr = "You must select 1 option";
    }
    else {
        $hand = $_POST["hand"];
    }

    if (empty($_POST["reservation"])) {
        $reservationErr = "Missing";
    }
    else {
        $reservation = $_POST["reservation"];
    }

    if (empty($_POST["time"])) {
        $timeErr = "You must select a time";
    }
    else {
        $time = $_POST["time"];
    } 
}
?>
```

Here is the html form I am working with:

```
<form method= "POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

<p  class="ex"><strong>Full Name:</strong>
<br>
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name);?>">
<span class="error"><?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
<br><br>

<strong>Contact Telephone:</strong>
<br>
<input type="text" name="tele" placeholder="Telephone Number" id="tele""/>
<br><br>

<strong>Contact Email:</strong>
<br>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Example@email.com" id="email""/>
<!-- Party requirments -->

<br><br>
<strong>Select Party Size:</strong>
<br>
<select name="party" id="party">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value="5">1 Person (£5)</option>
<option value="10">2 People (£10)</option>
<option value="15">3 People (£15)</option>
<option value="20">4 People (£20)</option>
<option value="25">5 People (£25)</option>
<option value="30">6 People (£30)</option>
<option value="35">7 People (£35)</option>
<option value="40">8 People (£40)</option>
<option value="45">9 People (£45)</option>
<option value="50">10+ People (£50)</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<strong>Dietary Requirements:</strong>
<br>
Vegetarian <input type="checkbox" name="diet[]" value="Vegetarian">
Vegan <input type="checkbox" name="diet[]" value="Vegan">
Peanut Allergy <input type="checkbox" name="diet[]" value="Peanut Allergy">
Gluten Allergy <input type="checkbox" name="diet[]" value="Gluten Allergy">
<br><br>

<strong> VIP Area? </strong>
<br>
Yes (+£5) <input name="hand" id="left" value="5" type="radio">
No <input name="hand" id="right" value="0" checked="" type="radio">
<br><br>

<strong> Reservation Date: </strong>
<br>
<input type="text" name="reservation" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" id="reservation">
<br><br>

<strong> Reservation Time </strong>
<br>
<select name="time" id="time" onblur="validateTime(name)">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value="17:00">17:00</option>
<option value="17:30">17:30</option>
<option value="18:00">18:00</option>
<option value="18:30">18:30</option>
<option value="19:00">19:00</option>
<option value="19:30">19:30</option>
<option value="20:00">20:00</option>
<option value="20:30">20:30</option>
<option value="21:00">21:00</option>
<option value="21:30">21:30</option>
<option value="22:00">22:00</option>
</select>
<span id="timeError" class="timeError" style="display: none;">You must select a time for your reservation.</span>
<br><br>
<strong> Any Additional Information: </strong>
<br>
<textarea name="comments" placeholder="Birthday celebration arrangements, etc." rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
<br><br><br>
<strong> Total booking cost based on party size & VIP selection: £<span id="price">0</span></strong>
<br><br><br>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="reset" value="Reset form">
```

Ideally I would like this form to validate what the user has entered and display an error message if they have entered incorrect information to a field, or left the field blank. Anyone who has any suggestions to help me achieve this please help, I have been working hard on this task but havent had much luck :(

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to use associative arrays for errors, right now you generate a lot of new variables and it's very time consuming to write code that goes through it effectively.

So instead `$tele = $_POST["tele"];` use i.e: `$f_err['tele'] = $_POST["tele"];` that way you can go through errors easily, count them and display them under appropriate form field. Quite frankly your code is straightforward and can't see any problems with it.

Can you elaborate what is not working as it should?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, basically when I try and open the webpage and click submit I get taken to a blank page, instead of the errors for empty fields appearing. Also, instead of a blank box for the name field, it has "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name);?>" printed onto it once I open the webpage :(

Comment: You may have blank page because error reporting is turned off. Check your apache logs or error.log to see what's wrong - then get back to us with the occured errors.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with LukasS. The only thing I might add is to initialize the variables outside of the if statements. This will ensure the scope is properly set.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, would it be possible to link me to a pastebin with these changes present so I can get a better idea of what you mean?